# Testing a custom hook where useEffect should be invoked multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, preact

I'm trying to test a custom React hook, where i have `useEffect` inside, and I want a reference to it in the tests as I have to call it multiple times to test the behavior. It's about simple throttling:

```
export const useThrottleEffect = (effect, deps = [], delay) => {
    const lastCall = useRef(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const now = new Date().getTime();
        if (now - lastCall.current > delay) {
            effect();
            lastCall.current = now;
        }
    }, [...deps, delay]);
}
```

in the test, I have a basic scenario:

```
    let callback;

    beforeEach(() => {
        callback = jest.fn();
    });

    test("useThrottleEffect()", () => {
        const {result} = renderHook(() => useThrottleEffect(callback, [Date.now()], 1000));
        expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        result; //?
        expect(result.current).toBeUndefined();
    });
});
```

But I what a reference to the inside `useEffect` in terms to be able to call multiple times and check the callback. Furthermore, a timer could tick and check the behavior. Any tips here would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an utility component in your test, using the hook as intended to be used in your application.

solution outline (not tested):

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'

const Util = ({ number, cb }) => {
  useThrottleEffect(cb, [], 2500)

  return number
}

describe('useThrottleEffect', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers()
  })

  it('should work', () => {
    const cb = jest.fn()

    const { rerender } = render(<Util cb={cb} number={1} />)

    jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000)
    rerender(<Util cb={cb} number={2} />)

    jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000)
    rerender(<Util cb={cb} number={3} />)

    jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000)
    rerender(<Util cb={cb} number={4} />)

    expect(cb).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)
  })
})
```

references:

- Testing library [rerender](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#rerender)
- jest [Timer Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks)

Comment: That's actually a very good idea. I'll try it.